# Allow duplicate values in MySQL using Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I searched the internet for my question and didn't find anything helpful(or at least I didn't search well‍♂️)
The question is: My intention to allow different cats to have same toys relations (cat_id can have same toy_id of a different cat_id)
With my code duplicates in DB are not allowed.
Added MySQL workbench screenshot to accommodate a question. (Sorry for my bad English)

I'm using JPA for this task.
What I'm doing wrong?

[**mysql workbench screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDFLJ.jpg)

**Cat Class**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "cats")
public class Cat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float weight;
    private String color;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Singular
    private List<Toy> toys;
}
```

**Toy abstract Class**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "toys")

public abstract class Toy {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int id;

    protected String name;
}
```

**Specific Toy Class**

```
@Entity
public class Ball extends Toy {
    public Ball() {
        super();
        name = "Ball";
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(1)
public class TestCatService implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final CatService service;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Toy t1 = new Ball();
        Toy t2 = new RubberBand();
        Toy t3 = new Mouse();
        Toy t4 = new Ball();

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Add Pink Cat");
        Cat pinkCat = Cat.builder().color("Pink")
                .name("Mitzi")
                .weight(4.3f)
                .toy(t1)
                .toy(t3)
                .build();
        try {
            service.addCat(pinkCat);
            System.out.println("Cat added to DB");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Add White Cat");
        Cat whiteCat = Cat.builder()
                .color("White")
                .name("Mitzi")
                .weight(4.3f)
                .toy(t1)
                .toy(t2)
                .toy(t3)
                .build();
        try {
            service.addCat(whiteCat);
            System.out.println("Cat added to DB");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Add tricolor Cat");
        Cat tricolorCat = Cat.builder()
                .color("Tri-color")
                .name("shocki")
                .weight(2.7f)
                .build();
        try {
            service.addCat(tricolorCat);
            System.out.println("Cat added to DB");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Add Orange Cat");
        Cat orange = Cat.builder()
                .color("Orange")
                .name("jinji")
                .toy(t3)
                .toy(t4)
                .weight(6.2f)
                .build();
        try {
            service.addCat(orange);
            System.out.println("Cat added to DB");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Update Cat to Pink Color");
        whiteCat.setColor("Pink");
        try {
            service.updateCat(whiteCat);
            System.out.println("Cat updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Update Cat to Black Color");
        whiteCat.setColor("Black");
        try {
            service.updateCat(whiteCat);
            System.out.println("Cat updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }

}
```

**Console Output**

```
_______________________________________
         Testing "Add Pink Cat"                  
Pink cats are not allowed
_______________________________________
         Testing "Add White Cat"                  
Cat added to DB
_______________________________________
         Testing "Add tricolor Cat"                  
Cat added to DB
_______________________________________
         Testing "Add Orange Cat"                  
detached entity passed to persist: com.jb.lab4.beans.toys.Toy; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.jb.lab4.beans.toys.Toy
_______________________________________
         Testing "Update Cat to Pink Color"                  
Pink cats are not allowed
_______________________________________
         Testing "Update Cat to Black Color"                  
Cat updated
```

## **UPDATE**

I managed to get the code work as expected only when I explicitly add toys to database with toyRepository.saveAll(t1, t2. t3) and removing the cascade option in @ManyToMany annotation.

**Code below**

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order(1)
public class TestCatService implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final CatService service;
    private final ToyRepository toyRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Toy t1 = new Ball();
        Toy t2 = new RubberBand();
        Toy t3 = new Mouse();
        Toy t4 = new Ball();
        
        // manually add toys to database
        toyRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(t1,t2,t3,t4));

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Add Pink Cat");
        Cat pinkCat = Cat.builder().color("Pink")
                .name("Mitzi")
                .weight(4.3f)
                .toy(t1)
                .toy(t3)
                .build();
        try {
            service.addCat(pinkCat);
            System.out.println("Cat added to DB");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Add White Cat");
        Cat whiteCat = Cat.builder()
                .color("White")
                .name("Mitzi")
                .weight(4.3f)
                .toy(t1)
                .toy(t2)
                .toy(t3)
                .build();
        try {
            service.addCat(whiteCat);
            System.out.println("Cat added to DB");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Add tricolor Cat");
        Cat tricolorCat = Cat.builder()
                .color("Tri-color")
                .name("shocki")
                .weight(2.7f)
                .build();
        try {
            service.addCat(tricolorCat);
            System.out.println("Cat added to DB");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Add Orange Cat");
        Cat orange = Cat.builder()
                .color("Orange")
                .name("jinji")
                .toy(t1)
                .toy(t4)
                .weight(6.2f)
                .build();
        try {
            service.addCat(orange);
            System.out.println("Cat added to DB");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Update Cat to Pink Color");
        whiteCat.setColor("Pink");
        try {
            service.updateCat(whiteCat);
            System.out.println("Cat updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TestUtils.printTestInfo("Update Cat to Black Color");
        whiteCat.setColor("Black");
        try {
            service.updateCat(whiteCat);
            System.out.println("Cat updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "cats")
@Primary
public class Cat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float weight;
    private String color;

    // removed the @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) option
    @ManyToMany
    @Singular
    private List<Toy> toys;
}
```

Now with this change multiple cats can have multiple toys as expected.

If I put back @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) the code breaks with exception org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist.

My intention is not saving toys manually, I want them to be added to database with cats beans together.

Any thoughts why it doesn't work with cascade?

Comment: you want to have many to many relation, right?

Comment: @code_mechanic if i got it right. I also tried to replace the `@OneToMany` annotation with `@ManyToMany` but got same result with no duplicates allowed

Comment: Just putting annotation may not work, for many to many to work, you need to define relations from both side, please check this [how](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) to do that.

Comment: @code_mechanic thank you for the link , I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use one to many relationships like this.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cats",
            cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
private List<Toy> toys;
```

And in toy class, you can do it like this.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "cats_id", nullable = true)
    private Cat cat;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Cat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Singular
    private List<Toy> toys;
```

Check carefully. `@OneToMany` here means that 1 Cat can have many Toys. But `@OneToMany` comes in hand with another annotation in the other side even if you don't use it and make it unidirectional. That annotation is `@ManyToOne`.
So if you had bidirectional it would be.

```
 public class Toy {
    @ManyToOne
    private Cat cat;
 }
```

This would mean that multiple toys relate only to 1 Cat. You see where I am going. This relation does not allow the same Toy to be in multiple Cats. It is Many Toys to 1 Cat!

So the solution to what you want is `@ManyToMany`

```
 public class Cat {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
    
        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @Singular
        private List<Toy> toys;
```

This here means multiple cats have mutliple toys, and also in the other side even if you don't use it, it will be

```
public class Toy {
        @ManyToMany
        private List<Cat> cat;
     }
```

which would also mean multiple toys have multiple cats.

Now this allows a single toy to be mapped with 2 or more Cats.

Comment: I managed to get the code work as expected only when I explicitly add toys to database with `toyRepository.saveAll(t1, t2. t3)` and removing the cascade option in `@ManyToMany` annotation.

Comment: If I put back `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` the code breaks with exception `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist`
My intention is not saving toys manually, I want them to be added to database with cats beans together.
Any thoughts why it doesn't work with cascade?

Comment: update your question with the code that you use to make those saves

Comment: where is your cat that you try to save together with toys?